# What is the meaning of 2D vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dimensionality-reduction

I keep hearing people say something like:

> lets say you have a 1 dimensional vector of a person that just has his age.
>   Then you add another dimension which is his height, so you have a 2 dimensional vector

But I also heard things like

> A 2d vector is a rank 2 tensor

Can someone clarify which is the correct one?

Is it

`[1, 1]`

or

```
[[1,1],
 [1,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Tensor" is a very general term, meaning **N-dimensional array**. A tensor can be 0-dimensional (a scalar), 1-dimensional (a vector), 2-dimensional (a matrix), and so on... Tensor is a very encompassing term, meaning all of the things listed above. Sometimes, people use "tensor" to refer to high dimensional objects, as explained here:

> While, technically, all of the above constructs are valid tensors, colloquially when we speak of tensors we are generally speaking of the generalization of the concept of a matrix to N ≥ 3 dimensions. We would, then, normally refer only to tensors of 3 dimensions or more as tensors, in order to avoid confusion [...]

But please keep in mind that this is just a practice, and N-dimensional array is technically a tensor.

Coming to your question, if a tensor is more like:

```
[1, 1]
```

or

```
[[1,1],
 [1,1]]
```

First, they look like Python list and list of lists, respectively. Python lists are not mathematical objects, strictly speaking. Provided you imported `numpy`, it would be more correct to describe them as:

```
numpy.array([ 1, 1 ])
```

and

```
numpy.array([[ 1, 1 ],
             [ 1, 1 ]])
```

Now these objects have the mathematical properties of vectors-matrices-tensors. I think they could both be thought as tensors of different kinds and ranks. The first is of rank 1, the other of rank 2.

---

Other useful resources on tensors are [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-tensor), and [this explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5liqUk0ZTw).

Comment: Thanks for the effort and reply. It seems maybe I wasn't clear in the question. As I do understand about what tensors ranks mean, I wasn't sure if a 2d vector meant a 2x2 matrix or a vector with 2 elements.

Comment: 2D vector = 2D matrix = rank 2 tensor. 2x2 is a size, not a rank. 2-dimensional and 2x2 are different concepts. Sorry for not being clear about this.

Comment: Ah sorry! I knew that! 2x2 or 2x3 are still rank 2 tensors. Okay, so when someone says to me, i have 3 dimensions in my feature vector because we have age, height, and name. Is he wrong for saying that?

Comment: A vector with three variables: `age`, `height`, `name` is a 3D vector, i.e. a tensor of rank 3. Or a three-dimensional matrix, they are equivalent expressions.

Comment: And what is the shape of that 3d vector? If it was 3x1x1 or 1x1x3 that will make sense, but usually we store it as shape of 3

Comment: The shape of that 3D vector would be: `( n_obs , 3 )` where `n_obs` is the number of observations in you dataset, and `3` of course is the number of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

@Leevo has already explained it well. Alternatively, just ask Pytorch:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1, 1])
y = torch.tensor([[ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ]])
print("x dimension: {}".format(x.dim()))
print("y dimension: {}".format(y.dim()))
```

gives:

```
x dimension: 1
y dimension: 2
```

So your first vector/tensor with age and height of one single(!) person has only one dimension and your second vector/tensor has two dimensions.

Comment: So this is the way I thought too, however please read the latest comment on that answer

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can think of vector **dimensionality** as **list-of-lists-of-lists-of...**.

So,

1. **list** = 1D
2. **list-of-lists** = 2D
3. **list-of-lists-of-list** = 3D
4. and so on...

```
[1,1] # 1D

[[1,1],
 [1,1]] # 2D

[[[1,1],
  [1,1]],
 [[1,1],
  [1,1]]] # 3D
```

Then you mentioned:

> Then you add another dimension which is his height, so you have a 2 dimensional vector.

I think this can be interpreted in two ways:

```
[<age>] # 1D of size 1x1


# You can add height and make it 2D
[[<age>],
 [<height>]] # 2D of size 2x1

# or, add height and keep it 1D
[<age>, <height>] # 1D of size 1x2
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is the way I thought as well. However if you wanted to say we have four dimensions since we have age height weight and id, then itll literally be a 1x1x1x4 or 4x1x1x1 tensor which seems unneccesary.

Comment: I guess then you can either have a `4x1` or a `1x4`. You don't need to keep nesting like you did. More generally you could have `4xn` or `nx4` where `n=number of samples`. Then you are *always* at 2D.